# Large gaps in GFlot bar chart with value series

Tags: gwt, flot

I use GFLot 2.4.3 with GWT 2.4 and have a problem regarding a series of values, NOT a time series. x-axis shows several IDs and y-axis shows the corresponding values as bars.

The problem is that these IDs have large gaps in their numbering, for example 1, 9, 47 or 128 and up to above 4000. In a bar chart this is plotted as seen on the following image:

[image: bar chart with gaps]

Can I somehow deactivate these interpolation of points and get all bars aligned next to each other without gaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I could find is to use a TickFormatter.
Add your points to the model using constant gap as x-axis (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc.) and add a TickFormatter to the x-axis option :

```
plotOptions.addXAxisOptions( new AxisOptions().setTickFormatter( new TickFormatter() {
  @Override
  public String formatTickValue( double tickValue, Axis axis )
  {
    // return the label you want ("1", "9", "47", "128", "4000", etc.) for the tickValue (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc.)
  }
} ) );
```

Comment: That sounds very good and I made a quick test to verify your solution, it works!

Sadly I can't use this in my application for now, as the behaviour with the gaps is indeed useful to show missing values in monitored data, and changing the x-points from 1, 9, 47,... to a continous number would involve a Map to map these values. But I will implement this at a later time, thank you!